# A way to prevent matplotlib to remove the numbers on the axis

Tags: python, matplotlib, subplot

I am plotting a sample in 16 subplots together with one value in each of the plots, like this:
(example of first subplot)

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(4, 4)
ax[0, 0].scatter(C_CH_metalicities,C_CH_X_over_Fe, color = "gray", s = 3) #row=0, col=0 (100s of values)
ax[0,0].scatter(J072022_met,J072022_dict["C H"], marker = "*", s = 200) #(1 value)
```

Before the addition of the single data value, my plot looks like this:[Nice values along the yaxis](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b6e4Y.png)
And after like this:[Not nice values along the yaxis](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5X9nz.png)
The problem is the values on the yaxis. I want it to remain the same as it was before I added the single value.

I tried manually setting the yticks like:

```
ax[0,0].set_yticks([-1,0,1,2,3])
```

But this only gives a "-" in the positions of the yvalues, but does not show the number.

I know this is a very boring question, but it is doing my head in.

Comment: What happens when you interchange the two plotting lines? Try the star one first and then the scatter one....

Comment: @Redox this only reverses what is in the background/foreground. The ticks and numbers on the yaxis remain unchanged.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first argument of `ax.set_yticks()` is where the tick locations are, but not how they are labeled. You just need to add in the labels parameter.

```
ax[0,0].set_yticks([-1,0,1,2,3], labels = [-1,0,1,2,3])
```

Comment: You can probably also avoid doing this by simply putting the single point plot line first then plotting the rest of the dots. If you care about the star marker being on top, you can add in the `zorder` parameter. Higher `zorder` is put on top of elements with lower `zorder`.

Comment: Ok so it is like that. I tried that, but then it gives me an error: "TypeError: set_ticks() got an unexpected keyword argument 'labels'"

Comment: I tried this, but this does not do anything about the scuffed y axis.

Comment: Apologies, meant `set_yticks()` not `set_ticks()`.

Comment: Ah It worked now, apparently I had a too old version of matplotlib! Thank you so much!!